# Django redirect to a view with GET arguments set

Tags: python, django

I'm having a hard time understanding the Django System of views and templates. All I want to do is inform the user of the status of his request- he pushes a button and gets an infobox with a message. The button in the Dashboard is at the root of the URL and sends a POST request to the Django Web App at `book/`.

In the view bound to this URL, I check if the booking is valid and want to inform the user (without the use of javascript) about the result. I wanted to send back a HTTP redirect to `/?response=success` or `/?response=failed`.

I've tried to give the view of the dashboard arguments and changed the URL regex but this did not lead where I want it to go. Currently, it's just

```
return redirect('dashboard')
```

and the URL conf is:

```
...
url(r'^$', app.views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
url(r'^book/$', app.views.book, name='book'),
...
```

I really like Django - it's really easy to use. But in simple cases like this, it just drives me crazy. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Kind regards
Eric

Comment: The querystring `?response=success` is not included in the URL pattern, so you would simply use `return redirect('dashboard') + '?response=failed'`. Then in the dashboard view you can do `response = request.GET.get('response')`.

Comment: Or better you use the `messages` framework (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html)

Comment: And fwiw, if it's just about reading informations (no side effects on the server) the request should be done with a GET. POST is for submitting data for processing by the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @Alasdair I get a error when doing this:
`
    TypeError at /book/
    unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'HttpResponseRedirect' and 'str'
`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for the information. I will have a look at it.

Comment: It works. Thank you @brunodesthuilliers . Is it possible to mark a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: Oops, the correct code would be `redirect(reverse('dashboard') + '?response=failed')`. But the messages framework as Bruno suggests might be a better approach.

Comment: @Eric nope but if you really consider this as the correct answer, I reposted it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just [use the `messages` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/) - [that's what it's for](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html).

Oh and yes: if that's just for displaying informations (no side effect on the server), you should use a GET request - POST is for submitting data for processing by the server.

Comment: Thanks! This is really the best way to achieve what I wanted